# Azure AD - App Registration - Creating a new scope

Tags: powershell, azure, entra-id, oauth, azure-cli

I'm looking for a way to create a new Azure Active Directory application registration via a PowerShell script.  I can create the application using the following script:

```perl
$appName = "CliApp"

az ad app create --display-name "$appName" --oauth2-allow-implicit-flow true
$appJson = az ad app list --query "[?displayName=='$appName']"
$app = $appJson | ConvertFrom-Json
az ad app update --id $app.appId --identifier-uris api://$($app.appId) api://$($appName.ToLower())
```

But as I understand it, in order to create a new scope, I need to call Graph API.  Is that correct?  Are there any examples on how to do that via Powershell?  If so, how do I get an auth token using my credentials from Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use portal.azure.com > Azure Active Directory > App registration
Manually create using web browser, and then see / export whole manifest.json with all details and configuration, including scopes to Microsoft Graph API or whatever you need.

Then you can use script using Azure CLI:

```
az ad app create --display-name "$appName" --required-resource-accesses @manifest.json
```

more info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_create